# How to pass a C++ Template instance to a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, generics

How can I pass any object of an templated class to another function in **C++11**?

In the snippet below `passInObj` does not compile because it complains about `Printer&`. I want to pass in any `Printer` it does not matter which template `T` I have used.

**How can I do this and why does the solution below not work?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
template <typename T>
class Printer {
  public:
   Printer(const T& tl) : t(tl) {}
   void print() const {
     for (auto x : t) {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
      }
   }
   const T &t;
};

// THIS LINE DOES NOT COMPILE
void passInObj(const Printer& p) {
   p.print();
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> vec;
  vec.push_back("ABC");
  Printer<std::vector<std::string>> printer(vec);
  printer.print();
  passInObj(p);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I do this

You need to make it into a function template:

```
template <class T>
void passInObj(const Printer<T>& p) {
    p.print();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s7b4xh5eM)

> and why does the solution below not work?

Because `Printer` is not a type, it's only a template. For `passInObj` to work with any `Printer<T>`, you need to make the function into a function template so that it'll be instantiated for every `Printer<T>` which is used to call it.

Answer (score 1):

While @TedLyngmo's answer should be your go-to by default, you can also do this via a polymorphic interface if you cannot make `passInObj()` a template for some reason or other.

This is done by adding a base interface class that will be derived by all `Printer<>` classes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class IPrinter {
  public:
    virtual void print() const = 0;

  // Either that or public and virtual
  protected:
    ~IPrinter() = default;
};

template <typename T>
class Printer : public IPrinter {
  public:
   Printer(const T& tl) : t(tl) {}
   void print() const override {
     for (auto x : t) {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
      }
   }
   const T &t;
};

void passInObj(const IPrinter& p) {
   p.print();
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> vec;
  vec.push_back("ABC");
  Printer<std::vector<std::string>> printer(vec);
  printer.print();
  passInObj(p);
  return 0;
}
```